# Build failure after adding dependency ,Android Gradle Plugin version mismatch

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I encountered a peculiar situation and was hoping to seek some assistance from you guys. After adding a new dependency to my project `com.helpscout:beacon:5.0.1` , the build fails with the following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsStaging'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:stagingRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :common:base > com.helpscout:beacon:5.0.1
      > No matching variant of com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'staging', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.2:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a platform for use during compile-time and the consumer needed a library for use during runtime
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.2.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'staging')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
          - Variant 'enforcedApiElements' capability com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom-derived-enforced-platform:4.9.2:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an enforced platform for use during compile-time and the consumer needed a library for use during runtime
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.2.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'staging')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
          - Variant 'enforcedRuntimeElements' capability com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom-derived-enforced-platform:4.9.2 declares a component for use during runtime:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an enforced platform and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.2.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'staging')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.2 declares a component for use during runtime:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a platform and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.2.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'staging')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
```

I have a multimodule project, and the only change made was adding the above dependency to the `:common:base` module's `build.gradle` file. That's why I'm not posting any other code.

I don't use OkHttp in my project, nor do I have a declared dependency on it. It raised my suspicion that the error log mentions the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version my project is using (specifically version 8.2.1 in the log). So, I investigated to see if the difference in AGP versions is causing the problem.

I discovered that Help Scout uses Android Gradle Plugin version 8.0.2 with Gradle version 8.1, while my project uses Android Gradle Plugin version 8.2.0 and Gradle version 8.2. This led me to downgrade my AGP version to 8.1.1 ( note it is even not the 8.0.2 which help scout uses), which successfully fixed the issue, and everything works fine.

While the problem is solved, I prefer not to have solutions that I don't understand or be in a situation where I don't comprehend the root cause of the problem. I checked other dependencies in my project, and many of them use AGP versions older than what I use in my project. Why is it that only Help Scout is breaking the build? Or perhaps, the difference in AGP versions is not the root cause of the problem at all.

Does anybody have insight or experience with something similar? I would really like to understand the true reason behind this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/helpscout/beacon-android-sdk-sample/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md indicates they have pinned their dependency to 8.1 for Gradle. They likely need to update their SDK for this to work and I have reached out to their support team.